# How locate error "Login failed for user 'user_test'" inside huge stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I am in the process of refactoring legacy system which relies on huge a stored procedure with large calling tree of dependent stored procedures/UDFs and a lot of interconnected linked servers.

Production stored procedure runs fine while test one fails with

> Login failed for user 'user_test'

I can get no further details from `error_procedure() and error_line()`.

Complete output:

> (1 row affected)
>
> (1 row affected)
>
> ...skipped
>
> ErrorNumber=[18456]; ErrorSeverity=[14]; ErrorState=[1]; ErrorProcedure=[]; ErrorLine=[1]; ErrorMessage=[Login failed for user 'user_test'.]
>
> Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Login failed for user 'user_test'.

Apparently some of the linked servers are not properly setup on the test environment. So I would need to either set them up or mock/comment external calls. I cannot debug the stored procedure on a test server.

How to find exact line in the code which throws this error without adding traces after each line of SQL?

System runs in SQL Server 2016 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: You could add some `PRINT` statements to add more verbose output to the messages pane; that would help you narrow it down.

Comment: It would be the last resort as there are 10000+ lines of SQL in total.

Comment: Does your test have user called `user_test`?

Comment: Yes, it does. There is an SQL security set up. `user_test` is the name of both sql login and database user.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu - cleverly placed `Print` statements will help you zero in on the problem line(s) in a few executions.  Starting with 10K lines, in four iterations you could have the range narrowed down to 600 lines.  It's not elegant, but it'll get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Profiler can capture the individual statements in a stored procedure. See details [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29296/75565). Using such capture I have identified statement preceding an error. Then I have searched through SQL code using Toad. Problem was pinpointed. It was something like:
`exec sp_executesql 'select top 1 * from openquery(ext_server, ...`

If there exists more elegant solution to this - please post an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping entire body of your proc into a try/catch block and throw  from catch block, instead of relying on built in error functions.

you can also try to find linked server definition that has user_test login specified and try to check if it works. granted you may have to do it on all servers in the stack.

```
Select * 
from sys.servers 
    inner join sys.linked_logins on servers.server_id = linked_logins.server_id
where
    remote_name = 'user_test'
```

Comment: That is done already. Output `ErrorNumber=[18456]; ErrorSeverity=[14]; ErrorState=[1]; ErrorProcedure=[]; ErrorLine=[1]; ErrorMessage=[Login failed for user 'user_test']`

Comment: try finding a broken linked server that is using the credentials returned by the error

Comment: Well, all of them are[should be] broken. I cannot just figure our which nested SP/UDF calls any of them.

Comment: try looking for a reference in syscomments.text, check for either 3 part name reference, linkedserver names, openrowset, opendatasource or openquery functions

Comment: There are hundreds of references there

Comment: well, if all of your linked server are not working and your proc has thousands of line of code, you will most likely find multiple instances where proc fails in the stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194224/discussion-between-anton-krouglov-and-daniel-n).